# jQuery tipsy plugin causes wierd select element behavior on IE

Tags: jquery, tipsy

I'm using the jquery [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) plugin along side jquery unobtrusive validation in an ASP.NET MVC project. I'm using the following code to wireup Tipsy to the validation code:

```
$(function () {

    var options = {
        fade: true,
        trigger: 'focus',
        gravity: 's',
        opacity: 1,
        offset: 8
    };

    var validator = $('form').data('validator');

    if (validator) {

        // handle plugin events
        validator.settings.success = function () { }
        validator.settings.errorPlacement = function (errorElement, inputElement) {
            errorElement.hide();
            inputElement.attr('title', errorElement.text());
            inputElement.tipsy(options);
        }

        // handle cases where validation messages are 
        // provided by server side code via postback
        $('.input-validation-error').each(function (index, element) {
            element = $(element);
            sibling = element.siblings('.field-validation-error');

            if (sibling.length > 0) {
                element.attr('title', sibling.text());
                element.tipsy(options);
                sibling.hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This all works great. However, in IE (7-9, at least), when I click on a drop down that has a tooltip applied, the drop down menu appears and then disappears immediately. If I click and hold the mouse button, I can scroll through the drop down menu, but as soon as I let go, the menu disappears. This is not the expected behavior, nor does any other browser do this.

For reference, the HTML code for the drop down is pretty standard:

```
<li>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.BirthYear)
    <div class="field">

        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BirthMonth, new SelectList(
            Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x=>x.ToString("00"))), 
            Html.GetString("Label_Month").ToString())

        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BirthYear, new SelectList(
            Enumerable.Range(1901, 112).Select(x=>x.ToString("0000"))), 
            Html.GetString("Label_Year").ToString())                    

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.BirthYear)
    </div>
</li>
```

Any suggestions?